# Rebind previous event

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how I can rebind the previous behavior of a normal link!
example:

```
function removeDefaultBehaviour(objects){
    objects.each(function(){
        $(this).data('onclick',$(this).attr('onclick'));
        $(this).attr('onclick','return false;'); 
    });
};

function addDefaultBehaviour(objects){
    objects.each(function(){
        if($(this).data('onclick')!='')
            $(this).attr('onclick',$(this).data('onclick'));
    });
};
```

I tried to store the previous behavior in the data object of each link. But this didn't work!
Any suggestions, how to restore the previous and default behavior of a link!
Thx

Markus

Comment: how are you calling these methods? are you sure you're passing them jquery objects or should you be calling $(objects).each() instead of objects.each()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to handle `onclick` and other event handlers as strings, as DOM `setAttribute` or jQuery `attr` would do. Functions cannot be adequately serialised to a string. Instead use the normal DOM event handler properties such as `element.onclick` to get and set the real function objects:

```
function falsefunction() {
    return false;
}
function nofunction() {
    return;
}

function removeDefaultBehaviour(objects){
    objects.each(function(){
        if (this.onclick)
            $(this).data('onclick', this.onclick);
        this.onclick= falsefunction;
    });
}

function restoreDefaultBehaviour(objects){
    objects.each(function(){
        var onclick= $(this).data('onclick');
        this.onclick= onclick? onclick : nofunction;
    });
}
```

However, juggling event handlers like this is a bit of a smell and usually suggests you'd be better off using [bind](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind):

```
function preventDefault(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

function removeDefaultBehaviour(objects){
    objects.bind('click', preventDefault); // or objects.click(preventDefault);
}

function restoreDefaultBehaviour(objects){
    objects.unbind('click', preventDefault);
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Your 2nd suggestion is awesome! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function removeDefaultBehaviour(objects){
    objects.each(function(){
        $(this).data('onclick',$(this).attr('onclick').toString());
        $(this).attr('onclick','return false;'); 
    });
};
```

Without the toString() function, you won't get the code contents of the onclick event, you just get "onclick(event)".

Answer (score 0):

The data returned by `$(this).attr('onclick')` is most likely a function.

Thus on setting you would need to wrap it into a function again

```
$(this).attr('onclick',function(){return $(this).data('onclick')});
```

else the function gets executed instead of being set.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(selector).unbind('click');
```

You could also have a look at jQuery's namespaced events for kicks: http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events